# Handling Form Validation Result in ErrorHandler

Tags: spring, validation, spring-boot

I use spring-boot as a backend server. It has tens of Action Methods. As usual Some of them contains validation. Actually I use BindingResult and returns validation error for returning Http 400 Status.

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class ValidationTestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/validation-test", "/validation-test/"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody @Valid final TestData data, final BindingResult result) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Sorry incoming data is not valid!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>("OK!", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    private static final class TestData {

        @NotNull
        private String value;
    }
}
```

My aim is removing follpwing lines:

```
if (result.hasErrors()) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Sorry incoming data is not valid!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

IMHO it's a cross cutting concern like Authentication and Auditing. I want to handle it in a one global ErrorHandler Method. It's possible to throw a CustomValidationException Before executing the method. So I can handle the exception in ErrorController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can centralize the exception handling logic at one place, using `@ExceptionHandler` which is a `ControllerAdvice` from Spring.

You can look at [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)